# Fulltext index on innerjoin query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that selects columns usign an inner join on a table two times, one renamed white and one black.

I am applying a MATCH AGAINST research on the columns white_name, black_name and site, but it just works for the site. I think the problem is the fulltext index missing (both players.name and matches_new.site have a fulltext index), but how can I create an index on the column generated by an inner join?

Query:

```
SELECT id, date, site, game, white.name white_name, welo, result, black.name black_name, belo FROM matches_new
        INNER JOIN players white ON matches_new.white = white.id_player
        INNER JOIN players black ON matches_new.black = black.id_player
        WHERE MATCH(white_name, black_name, site) AGAINST('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit
```

Schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `MATCH AGAINST`, I used a simple `LIKE` query, which works perfectly in this case.

```
SELECT id, 
       date, 
       site, 
       game, 
       white.name white_name, 
       welo, 
       result, 
       black.name black_name, 
       belo 
FROM       matches_new
INNER JOIN players white 
        ON matches_new.white = white.id_player
INNER JOIN players black 
        ON matches_new.black = black.id_player
WHERE white.name LIKE '$search%' 
   OR black.name LIKE '$search%' 
   OR site       LIKE '$search%'
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT $limit
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work (but i doubt if it will perform.... ):

```
SELECT id, date, site, game, white.name white_name, welo, result, black.name black_name, belo FROM matches_new
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
               p.*,
               MATCH(name) AGAINST('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as M
               FROM players p )white ON matches_new.white = white.id_player
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
               p.*,
               MATCH(name) AGAINST('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as M
               FROM players p )black ON matches_new.black = black.id_player
WHERE 
   MATCH(site) AGAINST('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR white.M or black.M
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit
```

Comment: The search is working, but the join are wrong, I get some rows with the same value both on white and black (this is impossible). I found another solution, thank you for the help